# For each value of a column divide that value by the number of rows that have the same sequence in another column (counting multimapped reads with R)

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

This is a part of my dataset:

```
    structure(list(V1 = c("t00000406", "t00000517", "t00000519", 
"t00000589", "t00000589", "t00000598", "t00000804", "t00000938", 
"t00001008", "t00001156", "t00001156", "t00001156", "t00001165", 
"t00001165", "t00001165", "t00001265", "t00001265", "t00001265", 
"t00001511", "t00001562", "t00001562", "t00001599", "t00001703", 
"t00001703", "t00001703", "t00001710", "t00001710", "t00001710", 
"t00001710"), V2 = c(617L, 445L, 439L, 357L, 357L, 352L, 234L, 
192L, 177L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 149L, 149L, 149L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 
114L, 111L, 111L, 108L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L
), V4 = c("piR-hsa-3546", "piR-hsa-3454", "piR-hsa-3546", "piR-hsa-6909", 
"piR-hsa-6908", "piR-hsa-3454", "piR-hsa-3454", "piR-hsa-3454", 
"piR-hsa-3454", "piR-hsa-31261", "piR-hsa-14100", "piR-hsa-14099", 
"piR-hsa-28592", "piR-hsa-6592", "piR-hsa-6591", "piR-hsa-14099", 
"piR-hsa-31261", "piR-hsa-14100", "piR-hsa-6909", "piR-hsa-16270", 
"piR-hsa-16271", "piR-hsa-620", "piR-hsa-31261", "piR-hsa-14100", 
"piR-hsa-14099", "piR-hsa-14098", "piR-hsa-14100", "piR-hsa-14099", 
"piR-hsa-31261"), V6 = c("CTGTTAACCGAAAGGTTGGTGGT", "CACGTGTTAGGACCCGAAAGA", 
"CGGCTGTTAACCGAAAGGTTGGTGGT", "GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTCATC", "GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTCATC", 
"ACGTGTTAGGACCCGAAAGA", "CGTGTTAGGACCCGAAAGA", "TGTTAGGACCCGAAAGA", 
"CGCACGTGTTAGGACCCGAAAGA", "TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCGGC", 
"TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCGGC", "TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTCGGC", 
"GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG", "GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG", "GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG", 
"TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATT", "TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATT", "TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATT", 
"GTTTCCGTAGTGTAGTGGTCATCACGTTCGCC", "CTGAGGGTCCAGGGT", "CTGAGGGTCCAGGGT", 
"CGTAGTTCCGACCATAAACGATGCC", "TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTC", "TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTC", 
"TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGATTC", "TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGAT", "TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGAT", 
"TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGAT", "TCCCTGGTGGTCTAGTGGTTAGGAT")), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to "mutate" each value of column V2 divide by a value computed by the number of times the same "sequence" exist in the data. ->

Sequence GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG exist 3 times

```
    nrow(filter(my_data,V6=="GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG"))
[1] 3
```

Result:

```
filter(pir_onehun,V6=="GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG") %>% mutate(V2=V2/nrow(filter(pir_onehun,V6=="GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG")) )
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  V1           V2 V4            V6                     
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>         <chr>                  
1 t00001165  49.7 piR-hsa-28592 GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG
2 t00001165  49.7 piR-hsa-6592  GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG
3 t00001165  49.7 piR-hsa-6591  GTAGTCGTGGCCGAGTGGTTAAG
```

I thought of appending results to a new data frame with bind_rows but it must be another more "tidy" way of doing it.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>% group_by(V6) %>% mutate(V2 = V2 / n())
```

does the job. First we group by sequence and then divide by the size of this group, `n()`.

Comment: Hmm, that's way easier than I thought. Thank you very much, I need to study more group_by and n()

Comment: `n()` is just for convenience, you could also use `length(V2)` instead. `group_by`, however, is indeed essential.

Comment: I don't even need to use a for loop, that's essential. I need to change my way of programming now.

Comment: Is this possible to become with the data.table way of grouping?

Comment: @KGeles, looks like it may be `dt[, V2 := as.integer(V2 / .N), by = V6]`.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the answer with the "data.table" comment?

Comment: @KGeles, sure, is there a reason you are suggesting it? Did it work?

Comment: I don't know for sure yet because I have a bit different "more effective" Data.table this time, but I'm stuck with the consecutive grouping of DT. For example I try to do:
`DT %>% as_tibble %>% group_by(Filename) %>% group_by(V6, add=TRUE) %>% mutate(V2 = V2 / n()) %>% group_by(V4, add=TRUE) %>%mutate(counts = sum(V2))->tb1` 
but with DT I struggle (haven't study it a lot)

Comment: @KGeles, that seems to extend beyond your initial question, so it's best to post a new one.

Comment: Done
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337831/consecutive-grouping-of-data-table-counting-multi-mapped-reads-with-r-part-2